# React Hooks Fetch API with data dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created an example React Custom Hook named 'useFetch' that takes in a URL, encapsulating the fetch API.

I can then call the custom hook to fetch data from an endpoint.

The issue here is, how do I go about using the result from my first fetch to pass into my second fetch hook call?

Inside my hook is an await call to the fetch API, but it does not stop the main component from calling the second fetch hook.

**Example:**

```
function Home() {

  const result = useFetch("https://google.com/");
  const result2 = useFetch("https://yahoo.com/", result);

  return ( <
    >
    // Use results
    <
    />
  );
}
```

---

**useFetch Hook - debugging implementation**

```
export default function useFetch(url, data) {
      const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

      async function asyncFetch() {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        setResult(res.url);
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        asyncFetch();
      }, [])

      return res;
    }
```

---

useFetch used to be a javascript function that was imported and used and we could define it as an async function to be awaited.

However, now that its a hook, we can't await the useFetch execution at the Home() level.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I've chanced upon that thread and saw that the 3x calls to fetch are the native api calls. 

I'm actually trying to convert an existing javascript function that wraps the fetch API, into a hook.

However, converting it into a hook doesn't allow for await to be used.  Therefore, the example doesn't work in this case.